# Create a library by linking link external library

Tags: cmake, bitbake

I am using yocto build environment for my project. There are multiple applications in the project and some of them are depending on one third party library(It contains the `*.s0` files, header files). So I am planning to create one static wrapper library around the third party library and link the wrapper library for all the applications.

The structure of the project:

```
.
├── App1
├── App2
├── App3
└── third-party
     └── inc
     └── src
     └── lib
          └── libdvm-hash.so 
          └── libhash-ipc.so
     └── CMakeLists.txt
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(hash LANGUAGES CXX VERSION "1.0.0")
set(LIBRARY_NAME hash)

set(HASH_LIBRARY_FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libdvm-hash.so ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libhash-ipc.so 
add_library(${LIBRARY_NAME} STATIC test.cpp)

target_include_directories(${LIBRARY_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
)
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC ${HASH_LIBRARY_FILES} ssl)

set_target_properties(${LIBRARY_NAME} PROPERTIES
                        OUTPUT_NAME ${LIBRARY_NAME})

install( FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config.cmake
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config-version.cmake
        DESTINATION
        ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME})
install(
    TARGETS ${LIBRARY_NAME}
    EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-targets
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})

install(EXPORT ${PROJECT_NAME}-targets DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${PROJECT_NAME} NAMESPACE dvm::)
install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/inc/  DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR} COMPONENT dev)
```

Now the problem is in the exported `hash-targets.cmake` the path to the library is hardcoded.

**hash-targets.cmake**

```
set_target_properties(hash PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "/home/mypc/path/to/the/ibdvm-hash.so;/home/mypc/pathto/the/libhash-ipc.so;ssl"
)
```

Is there any way to fix the hardcode path `.*so` and use the installed `*.so` from `/usr/lib`?

**Edit**
I installed `*.so` files in the target using `yocto`(using `do_install_append` command in bb file).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of linking with absolute paths, create an IMPORTED library for every such path and link with that libraries:

```
# CMakeLists.txt, building the library

# Create an IMPORTED target which points to the library shipped with the project.
add_library(dvm-hash IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(dvm-hash PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libdvm-hash.so
)

# Another IMPORTED target
add_library(hash-ipc IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(hash-ipc PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/libhash-ipc.so
)

...
# Link with those IMPORTED targets
target_link_libraries(${LIBRARY_NAME} PUBLIC dvm-hash hash-ipc)
```

That way, when create an export file for your `hash` library, CMake will create its linkage with **targets** `dvm-hash` and `hash-ipc`, but won't create that targets.

Next step is creating those IMPORTED targets in the export file for your project.

```
# hash-config.cmake

# Create an IMPORTED target. That time it points to the library in the target system.
add_library(dvm-hash IMPORTED)
find_library(DVM_HASH_LIBRARY dvm-hash)
set_target_properties(dvm-hash PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${DVM_HASH_LIBRARY}
)

# Another IMPORTED target.
add_library(hash-ipc IMPORTED)
find_library(HASH_IPC_LIBRARY hash-ipc)
set_target_properties(hash-ipc PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LOCATION ${HASH_IPC_LIBRARY}
)

# Include the export file for the target `hash`
# That file uses IMPORTED targets defined above.
include("${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/hash-targets.cmake")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I did the changes now the local system path issue is resolved.But target properties changed to `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES dvm-hash;hash-ipc;ssl`. But the targets `dvm-hash` and `hash-ipc` are not aviliable

Comment: The code in `hash-config.cmake` should go into your file `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}-config.cmake` which you install.

Comment: yes, it's reflected there. But `find_library(HASH_IPC_LIBRARY hash-ipc)` not found the library. Please check once my edit on the question.I Installed the *.so files in the target using `.bb` file its not part of the host rootfs.